# Ractivejs on-click events cannot be found when in array

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

Scenario: I have 4 buttons: one with fixed on-click event, another with dynamic event based on ractive property, and then 2 more within an array of objects that has the event configuration, as you can see in this code. http://jsfiddle.net/h060dmbk/6/

The data:

```
  data: { 
      "name": 'world',
      "text": "Say Hello", 
      "mainEvent": "sayHello",
      buttons: [
          {"text": "Say Hello In Array", "buttonEvent": "sayBye"},
          {"text": "Say Hello In Array 2", "buttonEvent": "sayHello"}
      ]
  }
```

The template:

```
<div class="buttons">
    This is dynamic, doesn't work
    <a href="#" on-click="{{mainEvent}}" class="button primary">{{text}}</a> <br />
    This is hardcode, it works
    <a href="#" on-click="sayHello" class="button primary">{{text}}</a> <br />
    {{#buttons}}
    This is dynamic into array, it works
    <a href="#" on-click="{{.buttonEvent}}" class="button primary">{{.text}}</a> <br />
    {{/buttons}}
</div>
```

The 1st and 2nd button have no problem, but somehow, ractive cannot find the dynamic event for the last 2 buttons when they are configured in an array.

is this a ractive error ? how can I have the buttons into an array to work ? I need to set a dynamic list of buttons with events also dynamic configured.
Thanks.

Comment: It appears to be working in `edge`: http://jsfiddle.net/h060dmbk/7/ -which is going to be imminently released as `0.7`.

Comment: thanks @martypdx , do you know if this has been spotted as a known issue ? our application is using 0.6

Comment: I suspect [this](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/pull/1546) was the PR that fixed it, but if you follow the links there were a couple other issues around it.